# CakePHP3: newEntity() Nulls Date

Tags: arrays, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to save an entity in CakePHP3 inside a Cake Shell.

This is the code I am using with some debugging added:

```
$this->out("PRODUCT: " . var_dump($product) );

$newProduct = $this->VendorProducts->newEntity($product);

$this->out("NEWPRODUCT: " . var_dump($newProduct) );

if($this->VendorProducts->save($newProduct)) {
    $this->out("SAVED");
} else {
    $this->out("ERROR: " . print_r($newProduct->errors(), TRUE));
}
```

and this gives the following output for Product:

```
 // Product: 
 array(5) {
   ["vendor_id"]=> int(1)
   ["vendor_sku"]=> string(15) "NW-ME-WL-MW150R"
   ["vendor_description"]=> string(38) "MERCUSYS 150Mbps WL-N BROADBAND ROUTER"
   ["vendor_price"]=> string(5) "11.00"
   ["date_fetched"]=> string(19) "2015-09-24 18:32:14"
 }
```

here you can see that there is a "date_fetched" property, yet after passed to newEntity(), this value becomes null. Below is the output for $newProduct after the newEntity() function has been called.

```
// New Product:
object(App\Model\Entity\VendorProduct)#57 (12) {
  ["vendor_id"]=>  int(1)
  ["vendor_sku"]=>  string(15) "NW-ME-WL-MW150R"
  ["vendor_description"]=> string(38) "MERCUSYS 150Mbps WL-N BROADBAND ROUTER"
  ["vendor_price"]=>  float(11)
  ["date_fetched"]=> NULL
  ["[new]"]=> bool(true)
  ["[accessible]"]=> array(1) {
    ["*"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["[dirty]"]=> array(5) {
    ["vendor_id"]=> bool(true)
    ["vendor_sku"]=> bool(true)
    ["vendor_description"]=> bool(true)
    ["vendor_price"]=> bool(true)
    ["date_fetched"]=> bool(true)
  }
  ["[original]"]=> array(0) {
  }
  ["[virtual]"]=> array(0) {
  }
  ["[errors]"]=> array(0) {
  }
  ["[repository]"]=> string(14) "VendorProducts"
}
```

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Might be the [column type](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#data-types), might be a [mutator](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators) in your entity, might be...

Comment: column type is set as "DATETIME", it's a freshly baked model and I don't have any mutators or anything configured... 

Right now I'm just manually setting $newProduct->date_fetched after I create the entity and before I call ->save($newProduct), and that seems to save it. 

It's weird though.

Comment: Well, guess you'll have to do some debugging. I'd start with **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.14/src/ORM/Marshaller.php#L122-L133**, check what `$columnType` and `$converter` are, then check where in the `marshal()` method of the the converter/type class the value changes to `NULL`. If the type class is `DateTimeType` it might for example happen [**here**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.14/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php#L138).

Comment: Maybe the data is being changed even earlier, like for example in a [**`Model.beforeMarshal` event**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.14/src/ORM/Marshaller.php#L199) listener, who knows...

Comment: I got the same thing and not from Shell. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Have you tried with `new \Cake\I18n\Time()` or `new \DateTime()` ?

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/291

Answer (score 1):

Basically as I commented above I had the same issue and I need to put the following line.

```
    $this->request->data['appointment'] = Time::parse($this->request->data['appointment']);
```

Inside this code:

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    $this->request->data['appointment'] = Time::parse($this->request->data['appointment']);
    $appointment = $this->Appointments->patchEntity($appointment, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Appointments->save($appointment)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The appointment has been saved.'), ['plugin' => 'CakeBootstrap']);
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The appointment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

I really don't want to parse the date each time I save a datetime field. I would really prefer it if  this could be automated. Don't know if there is a work around or it is something we do wrong.

Comment: using Time::parse() did fix this, but you're right it is kind of hacky. I'm sure there must be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue. Here is the solution which works for me.

I updated date column after entity patching. For example in your case :

```
$newProduct = $this->VendorProducts->newEntity($product);
```

after patch overwrite overwrite your array date column again like this

```
$newProduct->date_fetched = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // here will be what you wants to save
```

Now check your data again.Hope its working for you :)

```
$this->out("NEWPRODUCT: " . var_dump($newProduct) );
```